# MySQL Multi-Insert? MySQL DB integrity after failed INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, insert, myisam, database-integrity

Is it possible to insert a row into multiple tables at once?  If you do several tables related by an ID; what is the best way to ensure integrity is maintained in case an INSERT fails?

Comment: "Insert a row into multiple tables at once" sounds like a bad database design.  Insert the values into one table, grab that row's id (primary key) and update other tables with the id value accordingly.

Comment: so I should put over 200 fields and over 1 million entries in the same table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) are for. If any of the commands fail, the whole thing since `START TRANSACTION` is rolled back:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES(NULL,'foo','bar');
INSERT INTO someothertable VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'baz');
COMMIT;
```

This being MySQL, you can't use transactions with MyISAM tables (you'll need the tables to use some engine that supports this, probably InnoDB).

This will never be inserted into the table (normally you'd have some branching, e.g. an IF):

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES(NULL,'data','somemoredata');
ROLLBACK;
```

Caveat: SQL commands which change the database *structure* (e.g. `CREATE`,`ALTER`,`DROP`) cannot be rolled back!

Comment: Thanks!  My tables are MyISAM; I'll convert with 
>>ALTER TABLE mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;

Answer (score 1):

Use transactions, luke.

Comment: MySQL doesn't always have transactions, depending on the engine type.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can [insert multiple rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) (search for 'multiple rows') like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2), (value3, value4), etc...
```

However, there's no way to tell what got inserted and what wasn't due to constraint violations, beyond the query returning a count of records, duplicates, and warnings. You also can't use `last_insert_id()` to figure out the IDs of the new rows, as that only returns the LAST id that was created, not a set of ids.

If you need to guarantee integrity, then use single row insert statements and transactions.